# How does one compute the sum of a 1D array with BLAS?

Tags: vector, sum, blas

In BLAS level 1 there are *ASUM and *NRM2 that compute the L1 and L2 norms of vectors, but how does one compute the (signed) sum of a vector?  There's got to be something better than filling another vector full of ones and doing a *DOT...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BLAS does not provide a horizontal sum operation like you are seeking, because it's not an operation that is frequently needed by linear algebra libraries.

Many DSP libraries *do* provide this operation; for example, on OS X and iOS you would use the `vDSP_sve( )` function provided by the Accelerate framework.  Unfortunately, available DSP libraries tend to vary a lot from platform to platform, so we would need to know more about what platform[s] you're targeting.

Answer (score 5):

You can do a dot product where the second vector has an increment of zero. Using C it would be like this:

```
int n;
int ix = 1;
int iy = 0;
double y = 1.0;

ddot_(&n, x, &ix, &y, &iy);
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use a dot product with a vector of ones, more specifically to use the cblas_caxpy function.

Comment: axpy computes the element-wise sum between two vectors. The question was about a horizontal sum, or reduction of a single vectors' components.

Answer (score -1):

As seen in http://www.netlib.org/blas/blasqr.pdf, `xAXPY` supports vector summation.

[image]

Comment: I believe `xAPY` is for computing the vector sum of two vectors. The original question was to sum the entries inside a single vector.